# Show/Hide ReactJS components without losing their internal state?

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

I've been hiding/showing react components by not rendering them, for example:

```
render: function() {
  var partial;
  if (this.state.currentPage === 'home') {
    partial = <Home />;
  } else if (this.state.currentPage === 'bio') {
    partial = <Bio />;
  } else {
    partial = <h1>Not found</h1>
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div>I am a menu that stays here</div>
      <a href="#/home">Home</a> <a href="#/bio">Bio</a>
      {partial}
    </div>
  );
}
```

but just say that the `<Bio/>` component has lots of internal state. Everytime I recreate the component, it loses it's internal state, and resets to it's original state.

I know of course that I could store the data for it somewhere, and pass it in via props or just globally access it, but this data doesn't really need to live outside of the component. I could also hide/show components using CSS (`display:none`), but I'd prefer to hide/show them as above.

What's the best practice here?

**EDIT: Maybe a better way to state the problem is to use an example:**

Ignore React, and assume you were just using a desktop app that had a configuration dialog with a Tab component called A, which has 2 tabs, named 1 and 2.

Say that tab A.1 has an email text field and you fill in your email address. Then you click on Tab A.2 for a second, then click back to Tab A.1. What's happened? Your email address wouldn't be there anymore, it would've been reset to nothing because the internal state wasn't stored anywhere.

Internalizing the state works as suggested in one of the answers below, but only for the component and it's immediate children. If you had components arbitrarily nested in other components, say Tabs in Tabs in Tabs, the only way for them to keep their internal state around is to either externalize it somewhere, or use the `display:none` approach which actually keeps all the child components around at all times.

It just seems to me that this type of data isn't data you want dirtying up your app state... or even want to even have to think about. It seems like data you should be able to control at a parent component level, and choose to either keep or discard, without using the `display:none` approach and without concerning yourself with details on how it's stored.

Comment: I understand this question answered . But isnt what you have done is a routing concern . Do we need to handle by hiding and showing. Can the state be moved to a different object as a best practice .

Comment: Sorry i didn't see this before - it maybe look like a routing concern in this example, but this could happen at any level in the hierarchy.... Deep in a page, and then the same concern would come about then, too.

Comment: Note that removing elements from the DOM generally causes loss of state (e.g. jQuery data, <object>), so React's behavior isn't out of keeping.  React essentially gives us the option to hide/show or remove/recreate a child component.  A parent should know which option is appropriate for its use case (e.g. Tabs would require option 2).  I wish the child itself didn't have to care which option the parent uses, but it does if it depends on life cycle events.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option would be to move the conditional inside the component itself:

```
Bio = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        if(this.props.show) {
            return <p>bio comp</p>
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
});

<Bio show={isBioPage} />
```

Whether this is "best practise" or not probably depends on the exact situation.

Comment: but if this component was embedded deep in another component, that top level component would get rid of your component if it did the same thing with it's children, and the problem would continue.

Comment: Well yeah. That makes sense, what would expect to happen? I'm not sure what you're suggesting is a practical concern.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... I've added an additional edit to the question itself to further describe what I see as the problem!

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, `style={{display: 'none'}}` trick only works on normal DOM element, not React component. I have to wrap component inside a div. So I don't have to cascade the state to subcomponent.

```
<div className="content">
  <div className={this.state.curTab == 'securities' ? 'active' : ''}>
    <Securities />
  </div>
  <div className={this.state.curTab == 'plugins' ? 'active' : ''}>
    <Plugins />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like [official documentation suggests](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#stateful-children) hiding stateful children with `style={{display: 'none'}}`

Comment: even though I accepted this as the answer, this would mean that for this component and any parent component would have to know not to blindly recreate it's children, that it had to hide/show them. Which seems to break the concept of having components that are black boxes and just wrap things up. So your whole app would have to hide/show things to just keep the internal state of child components alive? Sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @Brad Parks - In your code the parent removes/adds a child component outright. This example hides/shows a child component using css. I see no semantic difference. Colin Ramsay has the better solution since the child component is in control of it's own display.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem here is that in React you're only allowed to mount component to its parent, which is not always the desired behavior. But how to address this issue?

I propose the solution, addressed to fix this issue. More detailed problem definition, src and examples can be found here: https://github.com/fckt/react-layer-stack#rationale

> #### Rationale
>
> `react`/`react-dom` comes comes with 2 basic assumptions/ideas:
>
> - every UI is hierarchical naturally. This why we have the idea of `components` which wrap each other
> - `react-dom` mounts (physically) child component to its parent DOM node by default
>
> The problem is that sometimes the second property isn't what you want
>   in your case. Sometimes you want to mount your component into
>   different physical DOM node and hold logical connection between
>   parent and child at the same time.
>
> Canonical example is Tooltip-like component: at some point of
>   development process you could find that you need to add some
>   description for your `UI element`: it'll render in fixed layer and
>   should know its coordinates (which are that `UI element` coord or
>   mouse coords) and at the same time it needs information whether it
>   needs to be shown right now or not, its content and some context from
>   parent components. This example shows that sometimes logical hierarchy
>   isn't match with the physical DOM hierarchy.

Take a look at https://github.com/fckt/react-layer-stack/blob/master/README.md#real-world-usage-example to see the concrete example which is answer to your question (take a look at the "use" property):

```
import { Layer, LayerContext } from 'react-layer-stack'
// ... for each `object` in array of `objects`
  const modalId = 'DeleteObjectConfirmation' + objects[rowIndex].id
  return (
    <Cell {...props}>
        // the layer definition. The content will show up in the LayerStackMountPoint when `show(modalId)` be fired in LayerContext
        <Layer use={[objects[rowIndex], rowIndex]} id={modalId}> {({
            hideMe, // alias for `hide(modalId)`
            index } // useful to know to set zIndex, for example
            , e) => // access to the arguments (click event data in this example)
          <Modal onClick={ hideMe } zIndex={(index + 1) * 1000}>
            <ConfirmationDialog
              title={ 'Delete' }
              message={ "You're about to delete to " + '"' + objects[rowIndex].name + '"' }
              confirmButton={ <Button type="primary">DELETE</Button> }
              onConfirm={ this.handleDeleteObject.bind(this, objects[rowIndex].name, hideMe) } // hide after confirmation
              close={ hideMe } />
          </Modal> }
        </Layer>

        // this is the toggle for Layer with `id === modalId` can be defined everywhere in the components tree
        <LayerContext id={ modalId }> {({showMe}) => // showMe is alias for `show(modalId)`
          <div style={styles.iconOverlay} onClick={ (e) => showMe(e) }> // additional arguments can be passed (like event)
            <Icon type="trash" />
          </div> }
        </LayerContext>
    </Cell>)
// ...
```